# PHP Uploaded file name: Japanese character encoding

Tags: php, file-upload, character-encoding

When uploading a file with a japanese name, some characters are creating problem.
On a windows system, I want to save the name of the file as-uploaded. So I have to use 
`mb_convert_encoding($name, "SJIS", "AUTO");`
which works fine most of the cases.

Though, some characters like `①` as in `0423図表①` totally disappear at the end. It seems that when uploaded the name of the file is already "wrong":
it looks like `"0423å³è¡¨â .pptx"` in `UTF-8` and if I change the header charset with

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=SJIS');
```

it looks like

```
 "0423ﾃ･ﾂ崢ｳﾃｨﾂ｡ﾂｨﾃ｢ﾂ堕.pptx"
```

I am not sure what I can do in this case. I tried to replace the `①` character but I cannot even find it with `strpos()` before or after the encoding conversion.

Comment: Thanks. Glad you got it sorted. Which bit solved your issue, was it the `mb_stripos` function found the character correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To qualify my answer (to the downvoter):

> **Q: I have heard that UTF-8 does not support some Japanese characters. Is this correct?**
>
> A: There is a lot of misinformation floating around about the support
>   of Chinese, Japanese and Korean (CJK) characters. The Unicode Standard
>   supports all of the CJK characters from JIS X 0208, JIS X 0212, JIS X
>   0221, or JIS X 0213, for example, and many more. This is true no
>   matter which encoding form of Unicode is used: UTF-8, UTF-16, or
>   UTF-32.
>
> Unicode supports over 80,000 CJK characters right now, and work is
>   underway to encode further additions. The International Standard
>   ISO/IEC 10646 and the Unicode Standard are completely synchronized in
>   repertoire and content. And that means that Unicode has the same
>   repertoire as GB 18030, since that also is synchronized with ISO 10646
>   — although with a different ordering and byte format.

From: [The Unicode Consortium](http://unicode.org/faq/han_cjk.html).

**My Answer:**

Rather than `strpos`  use [`mb_stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-stripos.php), from the [PHP Multibyte string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) to find and replace characters. This should help your script detect and translate the non-latin characters.

If the uploaded file name (`$_FILES['var']['name']`) is already incorrect in the PHP script (*from output such as `print_r($_FILES)`*) then you need to ensure you are correctly encoding the HTML form with `accept-charset='UTF-8'` (or SJIS, etc.). I would hope you're already well ahead of me on this.

Also it may be advisable to add a few preconditionals at the top of your code, again using the PHP `mb_` functions add at the top of your PHP page:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); //or whatever character set works for you
mb_http_output('SJIS');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
```

Out of interest:

http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr37/

and

http://david.latapie.name/blog/shift-jis-utf-8/